# In the below ODE which equation have oscillatory solutions?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, oscillatory-integral

In my question here I want to know from the following ODE which ODE have  oscillatory solutions
\begin{equation} y''(x)+(\sin^2 x+1)y(x)=0\tag{1}
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} y''(x)-x^2y(x)=0\tag{2}
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} y''(x)+\dfrac{1}{x}y(x)=0\tag{3}
 \end{equation}

**Attempt**:I have used the classical theorem of  Sturm which assert for solutions of: $y''+a(x) y =0,x>0 $ , If $a(x)\geq a_0>0\implies \text{Oscillation}$ and $a(x)\leq a_0<0\implies \text{NonOscillation}$, From this theorem We have only solution of  Equation $(1)$ which oscillatory solutions, because we have :$\sin^2 x+1 \geq 1 > 0$ and it is a [Mathieu differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function) which it is Oscillatory, but its seems to me that is not enough because this theorem is not applied for  $a(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ because $a(0)$ is undeterminted , Another Idea I have used the folowing definition:

**Definition**: We say that solutions of $y''+a(x) y =0,x>0 $ are oscillatory if its solutions have infinity many zeros  this necessite to compute this integral: $N(x)=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle \int_{a}^{x}\sqrt{a(s)}ds$ where $N(x)$ is the number of zeros of solution of each ODE,$x\to \infty $, From this definition seems solutions of all above equation are oscillatory because after computation of integrals we have divergence to $\infty $ which means there are infinity many zeros of solutions of all above  ODE, My question here  is : Which above  equations have oscillatory solutions ?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you could check out Kneser's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%27s_theorem_(differential_equations)